# How can I tell autotest to not rerun all tests unless I explicitly tell it to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, autotest, zentest

Autotest will rerun all tests every time my tests start passing when they were failing. I have a lot of tests, and for reasons I won't go into, rerunning all of them is painfully slow.

How can I make it so autotest will never rerun all tests unless I Ctrl-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. Somehow. I'm not sure what happened, but I think maybe some plugins I installed fixed it. I don't know.

[Here is my ~/.autotest file](http://gist.github.com/raw/361619/f5203c4fcea71ab901b9061ff1579ba377fcbe62/.autotest)

---

Also, there's `$ autotest --no-full-after-failed`. Silly me.